# Python efficient way of comparing 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I have 2 csv files text1.csv which contains:-

```
1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8

1  6  1  1  516405  21  8

1  6  1  1  21  34

1  6  1  21  60
```

text2.csv contains the same data: -

```
1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8

1  6  1  1  516405  21  8

1  6  1  1  21  34

1  6  1  21  60
```

What would be the best way to compare them csv files and display the output in some way like:-

```
Line1 in text1.csv found in Line1 text2.csv
Line2 in text1.csv found in Line2 text2.csv
```

and so on and also the other way round.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is coding first and asking afterwards if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! But SO is not a coding site. It's here to help you get unstuck form a specific problem. What have you tried ? Show us some actual code of your models, your trials and errors.

Comment: As @sundarnatarajСундар commented, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1_name = "text1.csv"                                          
f2_name = "text2.csv"                                          
f1 = open(f1_name,'r').readlines()                             
f2 = open(f2_name,'r').readlines()                             

count1 = 0                                                     
for line in f1:                                                
    count1+=1                                                  
    if line != "\n" and line in f2:                            
        print "Line{0} in {1} found in Line{2} in {3} ({4})".format( 
            str(count1),                                       
            f1_name,                                           
            str(1+f2.index(line)),                             
            f2_name,
            line.strip())
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

**output**

```
Line1 in text1.csv found in Line1 in text2.csv (1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8)
Line3 in text1.csv found in Line3 in text2.csv (1  6  1  1  516405  21  8)
Line5 in text1.csv found in Line5 in text2.csv (1  6  1  1  21  34)
Line7 in text1.csv found in Line7 in text2.csv (1  6  1  21  60)
```

Comment: It works but I think my csv files contains blank line. It also consider them as separate lines and compare them too.

Comment: What if I want to display the actual values instead of Line1? I mean I want to display 1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8 found in Line1 of text2.csv??

Comment: you should be using with to open files and if you are not you should at least be closing them.

Comment: @AshokaLella, What if there is line Not found or mismatching ?? How this code can handle that???